# CMake make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/path/to/uthash/utarray.h', needed by `HelloTest'. Stop

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am trying to build some mixed C/C++ code to run some simple test code (HelloTest) as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cpp_header.h"
extern "C"
{
    #include "c_header.h"
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but I get this very strange error:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/user/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/c1d0f54d/c1d0f54d/Debug --target all -- -j 2
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/path/to/uthash/utarray.h', needed by `HelloTest'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now, utarray.h is part of uthash (http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/), and savvy readers will know that this is not a question of the `.c/cpp` missing - `utarray.h` doesn't have one.

The CMake file -ish looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(HelloTest)

# CPP stuff
find_package(CPP_PACKAGE REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CPP_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${CPP_PACKGE_LIB_DIR})

# C Headers
set(C_ROOT_DIR "/path/to/c/library")
set(C_INCLUDE_DIR ${C_ROOT_DIR}/src
                      ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/mtrand
                      ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/uthash/src)
include_directories(${C_INCLUDE_DIR})

# C Headers & Source [we want to avoid globbing]
set(C_SOURCE   ${C_ROOT_DIR}/src/bnp.c
                    ${C_ROOT_DIR}/src/bnp.h
.
.
.
                    ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/uthash/utarray.h
                    ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/uthash/uthash.h
                    ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/uthash/utlist.h
                    ${C_ROOT_DIR}/ext/uthash/utstring.h)
link_directories(${C_SOURCE})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(HelloTest ${CPP_LIBRARIES} ${C_SOURCE})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `C_SOURCE` variable to list of sources and headers, but use it in commands `link_directories` and `target_link_libraries`, related to *linking*, not a *compiling*.

Probably, you need to append content of this variable to `SOURCE_FILES` instead.

Comment: I see, so am I wrong in thinking that all libraries `.cpp` and `.c` are not to be appended to the `target_link_variables` directive? Moreover, I thought only the main project files were supposed to be added to `add_executables`? I am still new to cmake.

Comment: `.cpp` and `.c` are not *libraries*. They are *source files*. You can make library from these files using `add_library(<library-name> <sources..>)` command. After that, you may link executable with this library: `target_link_libraries(HelloTest <library-name>)`.

Comment: Oh I see, so in actuality since I do not have `add_library` the above stood no chance of working anyway. Hence, I must add my sources to a library, but not the headers (?), and then I link them to my target.

Comment: Actually, library is an alternative for making executable from all sources. But you are right about headers - no needs to enumerate them for building library/executable.