# "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1" on "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++, c, xcode, linker, cmake

Right, please bare with on this, it might be quite a long one, and one related issue was solved here (I think): [CMake make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/path/to/uthash/utarray.h', needed by `HelloTest'. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976279/cmake-make2-no-rule-to-make-target-path-to-uthash-utarray-h-needed-by/31983195#31983195).

I have been struggling for some days now to build a simple 'Hello World' programme which mixes C and C++, and pulls in various external libraries using CMake. For full disclosure it should be known that I am fairly new to C, C++ and CMake hence please be nice.

I am working in OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 (my googling seems to suggest this might be part of the problem). I am working out of the CLion IDE.

Alas, here we go, here is the programme I am trying to build:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Simbody.h" \\Written in C++
extern "C"
{
    #include "project_in_C.h"
}

using namespace std;
using namespace SimTK;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

We have a physics library written in `C++` a bespoke project written in `C`, for which the main header file is, lets call it; `project_in_C.h`.

Again; all I am trying to do is build a simple mixed `C/C++` project.

Now, the above is executed using CMake, and the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(HelloTest)

# Simbody
find_package(Simbody REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Simbody_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Simbody_LIB_DIR})

# Project C Headers
set(PROJC_ROOT_DIR "/Users/usr/project-c")
set(PROJC_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/src
                      ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/dir1
                      ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/dir2)
include_directories(${PROJC_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Check that it has found the most important header
find_path(projFound project_in_C.h PATHS "/Users/usr/project-c/src")
if(NOT projFound)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find folder containing project_in_C.h")
endif()

# Project C Source [we want to avoid globbing]
set(PROJC_SOURCE ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/src/file1.c
                 ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/src/file2.c
                 ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/src/file3.c
                 ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/src/file4.c
                 ${PROJC_ROOT_DIR}/dir1/file5.c)
# Make library from source files
add_library(PROJC_LIBRARIES ${PROJC_SOURCE})

# Tie together
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(HelloTest ${Simbody_LIBRARIES} ${PROJC_LIBRARIES})
```

So far so good, but here is where the truly mysterious problem arises. Upon build this is what I get in return:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/usr/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/c1d0f54d/c1d0f54d/Debug --target all -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target HelloTest
[ 91%] Built target PROJC_LIBRARIES
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloTest.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable HelloTest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_program_execution_wrapper", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [HelloTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But what the flippin' dynamite does that actually mean?

It is kicking up a fuss with `project_in_C.h` where the section the error seems to be referring to is written as so:

```
int program_execution_wrapper(int argc, char **argv);

int __program(int argc, char **argv);
#define main main(int argc, char **argv) { return program_execution_wrapper(argc, argv); } int __program
```

As ever, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Em...Undefined symbols is `_program_execution_wrapper` ... I don't see this symbol anywhere in you program. Is this maybe typo in your post? what if you change code in `project_in_C.h` from `prog_exec_wrapper` to `program_execution_wrapper`? And also, this function is not implemented in your code. For a start try something like this:

```
int program_execution_wrapper(int argc, char **argv) { printf("%s", "something"); }
```

Edit based on your comments:
See the following example:
We have two files (main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int a = sum(3, 5);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and file sum.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

So I've I would like to compile this program...it would be like this

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sum(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-22f955.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But if I include sum.cpp in my main program, then program will work as charm.

Comment: As I said, program_execution_wrapper is just declared but not defined. You define that with function body (code that is in { } ). See code in my answer. More precisely, function `program_execution_wrapper` in my answer is defined and yours is not.

Comment: Right, this is where my `C/C++` novice-status is really going to show itself... `program_execution_wrapper` is defined in one of the other source-files that is loaded in cmake via `add_library`. I did not write out all of them, because there are quite a few, and I wanted to show the general gist of my problem. So that function has been declared but lives in a different source file. That being said, the corresponding header file is not included in `project_in_C.h` - does it need to be for the target to be "aware" of its location, given that we have actually loaded the header files already?

Comment: if function is defined in some static library, then no, you don't need to include cpp file in which is defined. Otherwise, you must include file in which is function defined